# Abrir acordeón bootstrap basado en URL por medio del atributo ID

Tags: bootstrap, url, accordion

Me encuentro utilizando el "accordion" de Bootstrap. Lo he combinado con enlaces de navegación jerarquizados por medio de IDs y me gustaría que el acordeón se abriera con base en la URL actual. Tengo actualmente mi código en JS, pero sólo se expande cuando se ha visitado previamente un item perteneciente a la misma unidad.

Me podrían ayudar por favor.
Saludos!

HTML:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#unidad1">
            <strong>Unidad 1: ...</strong>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div id="unidad1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <nav class="">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">item</a></li>
                    ...
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#unidad2">
            <strong>Unidad 2: ...</strong>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="unidad2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">item</a></li>
                    ...
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#unidad3">
            <strong>Unidad 3: ...</strong>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="unidad3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">item</a></li>
                    ...
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var last = $.cookie('activeAccordionGroup');
    if (last != null) {
        $("#accordion .collapse").removeClass('in');
         $("#" + last).addClass("in");
    } 
});

$("#accordion").on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
    $.removeCookie('activeAccordionGroup');
});

$("#accordion").on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
    var active = $("#accordion .in").attr('id');
    $.cookie('activeAccordionGroup', active);
});
```

Comment: ¿Podrías aclarar mejor cuándo falla? He probado el código de arriba y parece funcionar sin problemas ([demo en JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3aa1sqam/))

Comment: Hola Álvaro, gracias por tu tiempo. 

Te mando el ejemplo ya aplicado:

http://disenowebakus.net/diseno-de-un-sitio-web.php

Supongamos que alguien ingresa directamente a ésta url. El acordeón no se abre en su categoría correspondiente sino hasta que le das clic. Me gustaría que se abriera por sí sólo cuando se ingresa directamente.

Gracias de nuevo por tu atención, saludos.

Comment: Quieres que si una persona entra por primera vez a un _deep link_ se abra esa categoría del acordeón, ¿es eso?

Comment: Así es Álavaro, deseo que se abra por sí sólo cuando se ingresa por primera vez a dicha categoría correspondiente al enlace activo.

Comment: les doy las demasiadas gracias por que me ayudo con un trabajo que tenia pendiente para la universidad. Con la informacion brindada y algunos comentario pude resolverlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí esta la solución, muy sencilla pero se adapta a esto:

**Javascript / Jquery:**

```
var url = window.location.pathname;
url = url.substr(1); 

$('a[href="'+url+'"]').parents('.panel-collapse').addClass('in');
```

1. Obtener la url con `window.location.pathname` ejemplo: **"/diseno-de-un-sitio-web.php"**
2. Quitarle el primer caracter **"/"** la diagonal a la url con `substr`
3. Buscar el tag `a` que tenga como `url` la cadena que le estamos pasando, despues, buscar a su padre con la clase `.panel-collapse` para posteriormente agregarle la clase `.in`

**Su código quedaría así**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    url = url.substr(1); 

    $("#accordion .collapse").removeClass('in');
    $('a[href="'+url+'"]').parents('.panel-collapse').addClass('in'); 
});
```

Saludos, espero sea de mucha ayuda!

Comment: SOLUCIONADO, MUCHAS GRACIAS RADAMES.

Comment: De nada, puede calificar mi respuesta con la palomita verde :)

Answer (score 0):

Lo que quieres hacer es que si una persona entra por primera vez en tu página usando un *deep link*, entonces el acordeón se abra de la misma forma en la que se abriría con la cookie. Esto lo puedes lograr añadiendo unas pocas líneas de código en tu JavaScript (sólo voy a poner el código relevante que es el del `document.ready`):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var last = $.cookie('activeAccordionGroup');
    if (last != null) {
        $("#accordion .collapse").removeClass('in');
        $("#" + last).addClass("in");
    }
    /* INICIO PARTE NUEVA */ 
    else if (window.location.hash) {
        $("#accordion .collapse").removeClass('in');
        $(window.location.hash).addClass("in");
    }
    /* FIN PARTE NUEVA */
});
```

Una descripción de lo que hace el código:

1. Primero comprueba si hay una cookie y aplica los cambios (tu código original)
2. Si no había cookie Y hay un hash en la URL (el *deep link* `#ID_DEL_ELEMENTO`)
3. Aplicar las mismas acciones que para la cookie, pero en lugar de usar el valor de la cookie, usar el valor del hash.

Con este código se está dando preferencia a la cookie sobre el deep link, si lo quieres hacer al revés, sólo tendrías que cambiar el orden del `if` y el `else if`.

Comment: Muchas gracias Alvaro, había probado la sugerencia de Radames y funcionó! Tu idea puede que también funcione. Aportaciones como la suya servirán de referencia para situaciones similares que se enfrenten a futuro otros programadores. Muchas gracias, saludos.